# Error: Operation type [setMachineType] failed with message "e2 instances do not support onHostMaintenance=TERMINATE unless they are preemptible."

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I received an email from Google on 20 Jul 2021 entitled:

**[Action Required] To continue receiving your Free Tier discount, upgrade your F1-Micro VM to an E2-Micro VM by September 1, 2021**

*"The Free Tier F1-micro VM is changing to the E2-micro VM as the VM to use for free. On August 1, 2021, E2-micro Free Tier will be introduced. Follow these steps to change your machine type to E2-micro to avoid incurring charges for continuing to use F1-micro after August 31, 2021."*

I stopped the affected machine instance, changed the machine configuration to:

- Machine family --> Series E2
- Machine type --> e2-micro (2 vCPU, 1 GB memory)

Saving the settings results in this error:

```
Editing VM instance "ubuntu-vm" failed. Error: Operation type [setMachineType] failed with message "e2 instances do not support onHostMaintenance=TERMINATE unless they are preemptible."
```

What steps to do I need to follow to change the machine type?

Thanks

Comment: This will also trigger if you have a specified platform type (e.g. Skylake), as E2 does not permit this. You have to deselect it and let it be chosen automatically before a machine type change will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the **On host maintenance** availability policy to **Terminate**. [Change this setting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options#updatingoption) back to the default **Migrate**.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that was an easy fix.